# hola quiero unir a uno solo 5 formularios que cada ves que voy llenando se va acumulando

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, base-de-datos, visual-studio-2015

tengo un proyecto  con tabla (datos ,documentos, tramites, servicios ,economía)  y cada uno esta en diferentes formularios  quiero hacer uno solo todo  y ya guarda edita elimina actualiza  cada uno de los formularios ahora quiero saber como uno todo que pertenesca a un solo proyecto  sus datos del proyecto y al final imprimir un reporte trabajo con c# 2015  y sql server 2014  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si es en c#, por qué está etiquetada como JavaScript???? ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta describiendo con más detalle la estructura de tu proyecto y mostrando las partes relevantes de código (como texto, no como imagen)?

Comment: Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para encontrar consejos sobre cómo mejorar tu pregunta y aprender más sobre cómo funciona el sitio en general.